# How can I store a large file in Attachments?

Tags: attachment, cache

Our team has built a caching system for lengthy data analyses that we're already using for two types of analyses. I'm working on a third type where the file size of the analysis (zipped) is over 100 MB, and I think that's causing a problem in creating the `Attachment` record with the file.

I'm attempting to pass the file as a string from JavaScript to Apex by calling the following function (from a Visualforce page):

```
@RemoteAction
public static void saveMetadata(String zippedData) {
    Analysis__c analysis = new Analysis__c(Type__c = 'ZippedAnalysis');
    insert analysis;
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
    attachment.ParentId = analysis.Id;
    attachment.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(zippedData);
    attachment.ContentType = 'application/zip';
    attachment.Name = String.valueOf(System.now());
    insert attachment;
}
```

Calling this method from my JavaScript results in an error: "Input too long. [1, 65]" I'm assuming that the "1" in the error message is referring to line 1 of the function. I've also tried editing the above function to basically do nothing other than write to the debug log and get the same error.

Looking through [Salesforce limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm), I find that the `String` data type has "no limit on the number of characters they can include. Instead, the heap size limit is used to ensure that your Apex programs don't grow too large." Following the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) from that passage reveals a limit of 6 and 12 MB for synchronous and asynchronous calls.

Again, this file is in excess of 100 MB. The analysis can take a very long time, hence the desire to cache it for a few days. How can I store this file so that it can be referenced later without having to always wait for the lengthy analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exceed more than 6MB character long strings in synchronous Apex, despite the admittedly confusing wording in the documentation.

As a simple demonstration, try the following code:

```
System.debug('a'.repeat(6000001)); 6,000,001 characters.
```

You'll get the following exception:

```
System.LimitException: String is too long.
```

Instead, you should be able to use the [apex:remoteObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_remoteObjects.htm) visualforce element, or call the REST API directly.